# OR-Tools VRP with multiple depots only works for dummy cases

Tags: or-tools

### Problem

I've implemented a MDVRP (multi depot VRP) using OR-Tools to generate delivery routes with multiple vehicles. However, the solver only finds solutions when the number of deliveries is very low (< 15). I would like to know if this is because an error in the implementation or if it's rather a limitation in the power of the solver.

### Model Definition

- **I have *D* deliveries to be included in routes** (all of them need to be delivered)
- **I have *W* warehouses that can be used** (every route starts and finishes at the same warehouse)
- **Each delivery has a pre-assigned warehouse** (the vehicle delivering it has to start & finish the route in the pre-assigned warehouse)
- **I have *V* vehicles with a maximum capacity of M deliveries per vehicle**
- **I want to generate the routes that minimize the sum of distances**

### Implementation of the multiple depots

Given that by default OR-Tools only allows to use 1 depot, I've done the following changes to have multiple warehouses:

##### Include virtual nodes

- For each vehicle (vᵢ) and warehouse (wⱼ):

  - I've created one warehouse starting node **start _vᵢ _ wⱼ**
  - I've created one warehouse ending node **end _vᵢ _ wⱼ**
- For each vehicle (vᵢ):

  - I've added a disjunction for all the starting nodes of that vehicle vᵢ so each vehicle only starts once: 
    `Disjunction(start_vᵢ_w₁, start_vᵢ_w₂, ..., start_vᵢ_wW)`
  - I've added a disjunction for all the ending nodes of that vehicle vᵢ only finishes once: 
    `Disjunction(end_vᵢ_w₁, end_vᵢ_w₂, ..., end_vᵢ_wW)`

  This is how I've set the disjunctions:

  ```
  routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(index) for index in indices])
  ```

##### Matrix values

With the additional nodes, the distance matrix needs to be adapted. These are the rules that I've followed:

*Original Depot*

- The distance from the original depot to any start node is 0.
- The distance from the original depot to any other node is INF *(Routes has to always start in a starting node)*

*Starting Nodes*

- The distance from any start node of the warehouse i to a delivery node assigned to the warehouse i is the distance between the locations
- The distance from any start node of the warehouse i to a delivery node assigned to any other warehouse is INF
- The distance from a start node `start_vᵢ_wⱼ` to the end node `end_vᵢ_wⱼ` is 0 *(Routes can be empty)*.
- The distance from a start node `start_vᵢ_wⱼ` to any other end node is INF.

*Delivery Nodes*

- The distance from any delivery to any other delivery of the same warehouse is the distance between the locations. For deliveries of different warehouses the distance is INF.
- The distance from any delivery to any start node or to the original depot is INF.
- The distance from a delivery to an end node of the same warehouse is the distance between the locations. The distance to an end node of a different warehouse is INF.

*Ending Nodes*

- The distance from any end node to any starting node, to any delivery or to any other end node is INF.
- The distance from any end node to the original depot is 0 (Routes always finish in the original depot)

##### Example of distances/costs for a dummy case of 2 vehicles, 2 warehouses and 3 deliveries.

Each node shows the type of node and the index in the distance matrix. For starting and ending nodes the vehicle and the warehouse is shown. For deliveries the assigned warehouse is also shown. The cost of any other connection that is not shown is INF.

[image: Costs for dummy case]

#### Python Implementation

I attach a draft implementation in Python. With the current input (3 deliveries, 2 warehouses and 2 vehicles) it works correctly. However, when increasing the number of deliveries to 15, for instance, it doesn't find a solution. Neither increasing the execution time.

```
import random
from typing import List
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
from enum import Enum
from random import uniform
import tabulate

random.seed(0)

INF = 1e15


class RT(Enum):
    DEPOT = 1
    START = 2
    END = 3
    DELIVERY = 4


class BasicElements(Enum):
    WAREHOUSE = 1
    DELIVERY = 2


class RoutingElement:

    def __init__(self, warehouse: int, routing_type: RT, vehicle, index):
        self.warehouse: int = warehouse
        self.routing_type: RT = routing_type
        self.vehicle = vehicle
        self.index = index

    def calculate_matrix_value_between_elements(self, other, matrix: list):

        # FROM AND TO: Original Depot Cases
        if self.routing_type == RT.DEPOT:
            if other.routing_type == RT.START:
                return 0
            else:
                return INF
        if other.routing_type == RT.DEPOT:
            if self.routing_type == RT.END:
                return 0
            else:
                return INF

        # FROM: Real Warehouse Start
        if self.routing_type == RT.START:
            if other.routing_type == RT.START:
                return INF
            if other.routing_type == RT.END:
                if self.vehicle == other.vehicle and self.warehouse == other.warehouse:
                    return 0
                else:
                    return INF
            if other.routing_type == RT.DELIVERY:
                if self.warehouse == other.warehouse:
                    return matrix[self.index][other.index]
                else:
                    return INF
            else:
                raise Exception

        # FROM: Real Warehouse End
        if self.routing_type == RT.END:
            return INF

        # FROM: Delivery
        if self.routing_type == RT.DELIVERY:
            if other.routing_type == RT.START:
                return INF
            if self.warehouse != other.warehouse:
                return INF
            else:
                return matrix[self.index][other.index]
        raise Exception

    def equals(self, other):
        return self.routing_type == other.routing_type \
               and self.warehouse == other.warehouse \
               and self.index == other.index \
               and self.vehicle == other.vehicle


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    r = 6371 * 1000
    return int(c * r)


def get_distance_matrix(latitudes, longitudes):
    return [
        [
            haversine(longitudes[i], latitudes[i], longitudes[j], latitudes[j]) for i in range(len(latitudes))
        ]
        for j in range(len(latitudes))
    ]


def convert_routing_elements(elements, n_vehicles):
    routing_elements = [RoutingElement(-1, RT.DEPOT, None, None)]
    for element_id, element in enumerate(elements):
        if element[1] == BasicElements.WAREHOUSE:
            for vehicle_id in range(n_vehicles):
                routing_elements.append(
                    RoutingElement(element[0], RT.START, vehicle_id, element_id)
                )
            for vehicle_id in range(n_vehicles):
                routing_elements.append(
                    RoutingElement(element[0], RT.END, vehicle_id, element_id)
                )
        elif element[1] == BasicElements.DELIVERY:
            routing_elements.append(
                RoutingElement(element[0], RT.DELIVERY, None, element_id)
            )
        else:
            raise Exception
    return routing_elements


def transform_matrix(matrix: List[List[float]], routing_elements: List[RoutingElement]):
    new_matrix = []
    for i1, e1 in enumerate(routing_elements):
        new_row = []
        for i2, e2 in enumerate(routing_elements):
            new_row.append(0 if i1 == i2 else e1.calculate_matrix_value_between_elements(e2, matrix))
        new_matrix.append(new_row)
    return new_matrix


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        route_stops = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            route_stops += 1
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += data["distance_matrix"][manager.IndexToNode(previous_index)][manager.IndexToNode(index)]
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        if route_stops > 3:
            print(plan_output)


def print_matrix(distance_matrix, routing_elements):
    headers = [f"({i}) {x.routing_type}" for i, x in enumerate(routing_elements)]
    matrix_with_row_names = [[headers[i]] + d for i, d in enumerate(distance_matrix)]
    print(tabulate.tabulate(matrix_with_row_names, headers=headers))


def main():

    # INPUT #
    n_vehicles = 2
    max_deliveries_per_vehicle = 10

    # Use 2 warehouses
    warehouses = [
        ["W_1", 41.2, 2.2, 1, BasicElements.WAREHOUSE],
        ["W_2", 41.4, 2.3, 2, BasicElements.WAREHOUSE]
    ]

    # Create "total_deliveries" with half assigned to warehouse 1 and the other half to warehouse 2
    total_deliveries = 3

    deliveries = [
        [f"D_{i}", uniform(41.0, 41.5), uniform(2.1, 2.4), 1 if i < total_deliveries / 2 else 2, BasicElements.DELIVERY]
        for i in range(total_deliveries)
    ]

    # END INPUT #

    deliveries_and_warehouses = warehouses + deliveries
    distance_matrix = get_distance_matrix(
        [element[1] for element in deliveries_and_warehouses], [element[2] for element in deliveries_and_warehouses]
    )

    # Create all the needed elements to solve the problem with multiple pickups
    routing_elements: List[RoutingElement] = convert_routing_elements(
        [[element[3], element[4]] for element in deliveries_and_warehouses], n_vehicles
    )
    distance_matrix = transform_matrix(distance_matrix, routing_elements)
    if len(deliveries_and_warehouses) < 6:
        print_matrix(distance_matrix, routing_elements)

    # Instantiate the routing elements
    data = {"distance_matrix": distance_matrix, "num_vehicles": n_vehicles, "depot": 0}
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.AddDimension(transit_callback_index, 0, 1000000000, True, 'Distance')

    # Define cost of each arc
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    def max_deliveries_callback(from_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return 0 if from_node < n_vehicles * len(warehouses) * 2 + 1 else 1

    deliveries_per_route_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(max_deliveries_callback)
    routing.AddDimension(deliveries_per_route_callback_index, 0, max_deliveries_per_vehicle, True, "Max_deliveries")

    # Create disjunctions between all the start nodes (one per vehicle) of a given warehouse
    for i in range(n_vehicles * 2):
        indices = [i + 1 + j * n_vehicles * 2 for j in range(len(warehouses))]
        routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(index) for index in indices])

    # Minimize number of vehicles used
    routing.SetFixedCostOfAllVehicles(100000000)

    # Setting first solution heuristic
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 10
    #search_parameters.log_search = True

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)

    else:
        print(f"**********************                **********************")
        print("********************** NO SOLUTION FOUND **********************")
        print(f"**********************                **********************")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem using an easier approach and now the solver is able to come up with solutions for hundreds of deliveries very fast.

The key was that I know in advance the corresponding warehouse of each delivery so I didn't need the START and END nodes and, thus, neither the disjunctions between them.

When building the distance matrix, the distance from the depot (index 0) to each delivery is the distance between the corresponding warehouse of that delivery to the delivery location. Then, the distance between deliveries of different warehouse is set to INF, a value higher than the maximum allowed distance in the distance dimension.

In this way only deliveries assigned to the same warehouse can be routed together. Finally, when building the solution I take into account also the preassigned warehouse of each delivery so I use the correct warehouse in each route.